# Parsing JSON with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, parsing, afnetworking

I'm trying to parse a JSON page in Objective-C by creating a subclass of NSDictionary and adding getSomeProperty methods. I have been able to do this with JSON pages that precede every [ or { with keys but am having trouble parsing the following sort of page

```
[        {"id":12345,"name":"name1","account_id":10002000015631,
          "start_at":"2015-09-02T20:24:13","enrollments":        
         [{"type":"student","role":"enrollment","role_id":821,
         "user_id":10000001736511,"enrollment_state":"active"}],"hide_final_grades":false,
         "workflow_state":"available","restrict_enrollments_to_course_dates":false},
         {"id":100000055661076,"name":"name2","account_id":100000230095635,
         "start_at":"2015-08-28T21:22:41Z","grading_standard_id":null,"is_public":null,
         "course_code":"name2","default_view":"wiki","enrollment_term_id":10003000007529,"end_at":null,
         "public_syllabus":false,"storage_quota_mb":500,"is_public_to_auth_users":false,
         "apply_assignment_group_weights":false,"calendar":{"ics":"https://someurl.ics"},
         "enrollments":[{"type":"student","role":"StudentEnrollment","role_id":821,
         "user_id":10000001736511,"enrollment_state":"active"}],"hide_final_grades":false,"
         workflow_state":"available","restrict_enrollments_to_course_dates":false}
]
```

For example, for this webpage http://www.raywenderlich.com/demos/weather_sample/weather.php?format=json
I am able to create methods

```
- (NSDictionary *)currentCondition
{
    NSDictionary *dict = self[@"data"];
    NSArray *ar = dict[@"current_condition"];
    return ar[0];
}
```

and

```
-(NSString*) cloudcover
{
    return self[@"cloudcover"];
}
```

to retrieve the string @"16".

How can I use a similar method to get the @"name1" or the id @"12345" from my first example JSON code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of dictionaries. To have an array of outputs you can use the following method:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getValueString: (NSString*)string fromArray: (NSArray *)inputArray {
NSString *outputString;
NSMutableArray *outputArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (id dict in inputArray) {
    if ([[dict class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        outputString = [dict valueForKey: string];
    }
    else {
        outputString = @"Name not found";
    }

    if (!(outputString.length > 0)) {
        outputString = @"Name not found";
    }

    [outputArray addObject: outputString];
}

return outputArray;
```

}

And use it to get name with:

```
NSArray *resultArray = [self getValueString: @"name" fromArray: inputArray];
NSString *firstName = resultArray[0];
```

And to get id with:

```
NSArray *resultArray = [self getValueString: @"id" fromArray: inputArray];
NSString *firstId = resultArray[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[` `]` at the beginning and end of your JSON string indicate that it is an array, so when you parse the JSON, you will get an `NSArray*`, not an `NSDictionary*`. The first element of the array is an object, so that will be an `NSDictionary*`. Access `id` like this:

```
  NSNumber* id = self[0][@"id"];
```

It looks like your `currentCondition` is a category on `NSDictionary`. If that's true and you want the above code to work, you need to make it on a category of `NSArray`.  If it's not true, I don't understand what `self` is without more info.